# Getting data back from a dynamically created control within an asp:panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, wizard, dynamic-controls

I'm currently trying to create a web based wizard tool. I have a Wizard page that contains navigation buttons and an asp panel that will contain the individual wizard panels.

```
<asp:Panel ID="wizardControlPanel" runat="server">
   <!-- Wizard panel goes here  -->
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="backButton" runat="server" Text="&lt; Back" OnClick="BackButton_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="nextButton" runat="server" Text="Next &gt;" OnClick="NextButton_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" PostBackUrl="~/"/>
```

One control dynamically fills a checkboxlist

```
<asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text ="Description for the wizard"></asp:Label>    
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ProjectSelector" runat="server" DataTextField="ProjectName" DataValueField="Id" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I dynamically load this control into my wizardControlPanel once the checkbox is populated.

```
WizardControl = (BaseWizardControl)LoadControl(("~/Views/" + e.ControlType.Name + ".ascx"));
wizardControlPanel.Controls.Add(WizardControl);
```

**The problem is; on postback I then need to be able to find out which checkboxes were checked server side, but the control no longer exists.**
I can't find it on the _page variable. Running in to problems (I think) because I am adding the control to a content holder. How can I get this control back?

Answer (score 1):

If you add controls dynamically in ASP.NET WebForms, you need to re-add them manually very early in the page lifecycle of the PostBack (e.g. by overriding `OnInit` and creating the control with the same id in this code) in order to be able to retrieve the values. See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/317794) for a How-To.

The following sample shows the basic steps. It consists of an ASPX-page that contains a Panel as a placeholder:

```
<asp:Panel ID="wizardPanel" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Do a postback" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
```

This is the codebehind-file:

```
public partial class DynamicUserControls : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected UserControl userCtrl;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
            CreateUserControl();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            CreateUserControl();
        else
        {
            lbl.Text = "The following values were selected: " + string.Join(", ", ((IGetSelectedValues)userCtrl).SelectedValues);
        }
    }

    private void CreateUserControl()
    {
        if (Request["UserCtrl"] == "A")
        {
            userCtrl = (UserControl) LoadControl("~/MyUserControlA.ascx");
            userCtrl.ID = "myUserCtrl";
            wizardPanel.Controls.Add(userCtrl);
        }
        else if (Request["UserCtrl"] == "B")
        {
            userCtrl = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/MyUserControlB.ascx");
            userCtrl.ID = "myUserCtrl";
            wizardPanel.Controls.Add(userCtrl);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic steps are the following:

1. The page determines the user control type to be created upon a Request parameter during `Page_Load` (or later if necessary). It assigns the ID `myUserCtrl` to the UserControl.
2. Upon a PostBack, the page inspects the Request parameters again and re-creates the UserControl with the same ID `myUserCtrl`. This is important so that ASP.NET can retrieve the new values of the control from the postback data after the page initialization phase. The hardest part is usually to decide which user controls to create, because the data that are available in `OnInit` is usually not too many.
3. In `Page_Load`, the user control can be accessed and the values that were posted back are available. The UserControls in the sample contain a CheckBoxList and implement an interface that allows to retrieve the values that were selected by the user.

In most cases it is easier to find a different approach. Maybe you can use a MultiView control for your wizard that contains the UserControls for the wizard pages as static content. See this link for a description of how to use the [MultiView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247215(v=vs.100).aspx) control. If there are not too many (*read unlimited*) different UserControls to use, this approach is much more stable.

Comment: I toyed with the idea of using a MultiView control, but have been instructed to re-use as much code as possible from an existing application from an excel add in. This limits me substantially. Retrieving by ID seems my only option, but I can't find it anywhere on the page instance/ wizardControlPanel.

Comment: @beatsandbosons: you don't find it because a dynamically created control is not there. You have to create an instance of the user control with the same ID and add it to the controls collection of your panel during `OnInit`. I've added a sample that shows the basic steps.

Answer (score 1):

It is there, you just won't be able to access it using an ID.  You'll need to find it by looking through the wizardControlPanel.Controls collection.  I think there is a property that represents the filename you used.  But it would be best to use the debugger to track down either where it is in the collection or an identifier you can use to find it.

Having done this once or twice, I think I also remember that you'll need to recreate the control prior to the OnLoad event of the life cycle so that the postback will be able to populate it.

As Markus says, there is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do.  But if you MUST load this dynamically, this is how you should go about locating it.

Comment: Unfortunately, because the content is user-dependent I believe I do have to load dynamically. I did take a long look through the wizardControlPanel.Controls collection.
I see your point though, that the control needs to be re-populated before it is loaded back to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong place. Page.Form as opposed to Page.Request.Form. Due to the fact the checkboxlist is already defined in the user control, it's name is traceable in this variable. This way I can keep the current wizard structure.